# Javascripts of Ajax called file not working on main page on Firefox but works on Google Chrome

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, firefox

I am facing a strange issue. I am trying to receive the contents of another file on main page using jquery UI tab ajax method.

```
jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
            ui.panel.html(
                "Error message." );
        });
    }
});
```

and

```
    <div id="tabs" class="jquery_tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://xyz.com/x/abc.php">First Option</a></li>
        <li><a href="#div1">Second Option</a></li>
        <li><a href="#div2">Third Option</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="div1">
         contents of tab2
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
             contents of tab3
        </div>
   </div>
```

as you can see I am calling abc.php on first tab. It contains a form and some validation javascripts.

This works fine on Google Chrome and javascripts of abc.php works without any issue on main page.

The problem comes when I use firefox, javascript of remote file (abc.php) does not work but if I use `alert()` on the main page from where I am calling abc.php, javascript of abc.php works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer myself. I was using `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` to execute Javascripts on both main page and abc.php.

Just removing the `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` event from abc.php did the wonder and now It seems working on both Firefox and Chrome.